# Update scene along with thread

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to have a scene progressively display the changes done to an instance of a class that I update regularly within a thread.

So far I have

```
 public void start(Stage primaryStage) {   
    Environment env = new Environment(10, 10);
    StackPane layout = new StackPane();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Vacuum World");
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Start");

    Text text = new Text();

    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Thread t = new updateThread(env, text);
            t.run();
        }
    });

    layout.getChildren().add(btn);
    layout.getChildren().add(text); 
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

and the thread in question:

```
public class updateThread extends Thread {
    Environment env;
    Text text;

    public updateThread(Environment env, Text text) {
        this.env = env;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void run() {
        int updatesPerSecond = 2;
        int nbUpdates = 0;
        int targetTime = 1000 / updatesPerSecond;
        long currentTime;
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        long elapsedTime;
        long sleepTime;

        while (nbUpdates < 10) {
            currentTime = System.nanoTime();

            elapsedTime = currentTime - lastTime;
            lastTime = currentTime;

            this.env.update();
            text.setText(this.env.show());

            nbUpdates++;
            sleepTime = targetTime - (elapsedTime / 1000000000);

            if (sleepTime < 0) {
                sleepTime = 1;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(sleepTime);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I end up with is after pressing the button, the thread runs and updates the environment correctly, but the scene only changes once, after the thread is done running, and isn't updated when the thread is running. Any idea on how to obtain the result I'm after?

Comment: May be start with [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `Thread.run` which runs the `Thread`'s `run` method on ***the current thread***. You need to use `Thread.start` instead to create a new thread.

Furthermore updates from a different thread should be done using `Platform.runLater`:

```
...
this.env.update();
final String newText = this.env.show();
Platform.runLater(() -> text.setText(newText))
...
```

Also note that a nanosecond is `10^-9` seconds = `10^-6` milliseconds. You should divide by `1_000_000` instead of `1_000_000_000` and probably do the timing after the environment/UI update since this could take some time too.

Comment: It works but I don't really understand the point about Platform.runlater. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: @Afunakwa Nodes are not thread safe. Modifying the UI from a thread other than the JavaFX application thread can lead to unexpected results or even to exceptions (which may in some cases not even be easy to reproduce because 2 threads are involved). `Platform.runLater` enqueues a `Runnable` to be run on the javafx application thread later which allows you to trigger UI updates from any thread.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ;)